# Example of a smooth $f$ such that $\sup_{t \in [0,1]}(f(t)/M - t)$ is not attained at $t = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative smooth function which is not identically zero. Let $M := \sup_{t \in [0, 1]} f(t)$. Is there an example of an $f$ such that $$\sup_{t \in [0, 1]}\left(\frac{f(t)}{M} - t\right)$$ is not attained at $t = 0$?

Comment: How about $\sin (\pi t)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(t) = 4t - 4t^2$ on $[0, 1]$. Then $M = 1$, so $$g(t) := \frac{f(t)}{M} - t = 3t - 4t^2.$$

Now note that $g(0) = 0$, whereas $g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2} > 0$. So the supremum is not attained at $0$.